# glob patterns doesn't match any files workbox

Tags: service-worker, workbox, polymer-3.x

I am trying to generate service worker for the Polymer 3 with workbox 4.3.1.

I have some specific files inside bower and node_modules I want to cache.

I tried adding "en-in/node_modules/**" to globIgnores and include specific files like - en-in/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.*.js in globPattern.

The config I tried is giving a error. I even tried adding globStrict: false. Even that didn't help.

Below is my workbox config:

```
    globDirectory: "dist",
    globPatterns: ["en-in/**/*.{js,json,css}",
        "en-in/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.*.js"],
    globIgnores: [
        "en-in/sw-reg.js",
        "en-in/sw-custom.js",
        "en-in/rev-manifest.json",
        "en-in/package.json",
        "en-in/workbox-v4.3.1/**/*",
        "en-in/node_modules/**"
    ],
    globStrict: false,
```

**I am getting the below error:**

```
One of the glob patterns doesn't match any files. Please remove or fix the following: 
{
  "globDirectory": "dist",
  "globPattern": "en-in/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.*.js",
  "globIgnores": [
    "en-in/sw-reg.js",
    "en-in/sw-custom.js",
    "en-in/rev-manifest.json",
    "en-in/package.json",
    "en-in/workbox-v4.3.1/**/*",
    "en-in/node_modules/**",
    "**/service-worker.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/ecc18673aab127c532168e4dafee65f6e47931b1/packages/workbox-build/src/lib/get-file-details.js#L27-L32) that does glob-ing in Workbox looks like:

```
globbedFiles = glob.sync(globPattern, {
  cwd: globDirectory,
  follow: globFollow,
  ignore: globIgnores,
  strict: globStrict,
});
```

Because you're passing in `"en-in/node_modules/**"` as one of the `globIgnores` patterns, `"en-in/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.*.js"` is never going to match anything. In the [`glob` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob), `ignore` always takes precedence.

You have a number of approaches that would fix this:

- As part of your build process, move the `custom-elements-es5-adapter.*.js` file out of `node_modules` and into a different directory, and load it from there.
- Change your `"en-in/**/*.{js,json,css}"` in `globPatterns` to something like `"en-in/{dir1,dir2,dir3}/**/*.{js,json,css}"` so that it does not match `node_modules` by default, and remove `"en-in/node_modules/**"` from `globIgnores`. You can then leave `"en-in/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.*.js"` in `globPatterns`, and it will not longer be ignored.
- Change your `"en-in/node_modules/**"` in `globIgnores` so that it doesn't match `en-in/node_modules/@webcomponents`. (I forget the syntax for doing that, but you might be able to figure it out if the other two options don't work.)

There are probably a few other alternatives as well. But hopefully that explains the root cause.

Comment: Yes. It does explain. Thanks for the help Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

Here below the Polymer 3 notes at its page for service worker. They made easy of life :)

> Service Worker

A Service Worker is loaded and registered in the index.html file. However, during development (to make debugging easier), the Service Worker does not actually exist, and only a stub file is used.

The production time Service Worker is automatically created during build time, i.e. by running npm run build or npm run build:static. This file is generated based on the polymer.json and sw-precache-config.js configuration files, and you can find it under each of the build directories:

```
build/
├── es5-bundled/
|   └── service-worker.js
├── es6-bundled/
|   └── service-worker.js
├── esm-bundled/
|   └── service-worker.js
└── ...
```

By default, all of the source files (inside the /src directory) will be pre-cached, as specified in the sw-precache-config.js configuration file. If you want to change this behaviour, check out the sw-precache-config docs.

Source: https://pwa-starter-kit.polymer-project.org/building-and-deploying

Comment: I am aware of the service worker generation option in polymer cli. But sw-precache is deprecated and I don't want to use the same. But thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was resolved when I explicitly changed the globPatterns to the following

```
    globPatterns: [
    '**/*.js',
    '**/*.html',
    '**/*.css',
    '**/*.json',
    '**/*.svg',
    '**/*.png',
    '**/*.gif',
    '**/*.txt',
],
```